# Trying to get a match with regex

Tags: regex

I've got the following text with a variable whitespace at the beginning:

```
       Total Saving: 84%
```

I'm having trouble getting a match. From what I have learnt so far (new to regex). This should be close to working (I only need to match on either side of the text):

`[\s]* Total Saving: [0-9%]*`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does what it does differ from what you want?

Comment: This works unless there is *no* whitespace before or after `Total Saving:` because the literal spaces in the regex are significant.

Comment: Your regex will also match "Total Saving: %123%123%%%"; you could change it to "[\s]* Total Saving: [0-9]+%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a capturing group to hold the result, and the percent sign `%` should not occur more than once in the string.

`\s*Total Saving:\s*([0-9]+)%` (a bit more flexible on the whitespace in the middle) - the first group will contain the actual percentage.

Comment: I strongly suggest reading "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl (O'Reilly). That way you can become one even sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   /^\s+Total\sSaving:\s+([0-9]{1,3})%$/
```

to get only the digits (I assume its a range from 0..100). Works for several lines.

Comment: What is the $/m at the end doing? and {1,3} ?

Comment: ^..$ indicate that the whole line is matched by the regex. I think you don't need the m here because the regex doesn't look for a linebreak (M says: between ^..$ can be a linebreak (\n)). I corrected this, thanks. {1,3} says that there have to be 1 to 3 digits. + would look up 1 to infinite digits.